# Bounding the difference of step functions

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, step-function

I'm having trouble seeing the justification for what I assume should be a very simple step in a paper's calculations.

Let n be a natural number and define $\phi^n_s:=(ns)\wedge1\vee0=\max(\min(ns,1),0)$. Show that for any two arbitary real numbers $t_1$ and $t_2$ greater than or equal to zero,
$$|\phi^n_{t_1-s}-\phi^n_{t_2-s}|\leq n|(t_1-s)-(t_2-s)|=n|t_1-t_2|.$$

Comment: So if $n$ is a natural number, i.e. a nonnegative integer, then $n t \ge 0$ for all $t\ge 0$. Hence $min(nt, 1) \ge 0$. So what is the point of the $max(..) ? $ Or do you mean that $n$ is an integer?

Comment: @JustANoob The max is there because we are considering translated functions of the form $\phi^n_{c-t}$ where $c$ is a constant. Without the max these functions may go negative which isn't what we need in the paper's set up. Consider $\phi^n_{2-t}$, then if we ignored the maximum part the function would be negative for all $t\geq 2$ when we want non-negativity.

Comment: You defined the function for $t\ge 0$, so it is undefined for $t<0$. Hence it is undefined at $2-t_k$ if $t_k > 2$. Something is off in the definition.

Comment: @JustANoob Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(n,t):= \phi_t^n. $The variable $s$ is irrelevant. Consider the following cases:

$$nt<0 \implies \phi(n,t) = 0$$
$$0\le nt \le 1 \implies \phi(n,t) = n t$$
$$nt > 1 \implies \phi(n,t) = 1$$

Now, you can see that for any combination $nt_1, nt_2$ that you pick from above, the inequality holds. Take for example $0\le nt_1, nt_2 \le1$. Then:

$$|\phi(n, t_1) - \phi(n, t_2)| = |nt_1 - nt_2| = n|t_1 - t_2|$$

Now convince yourself that for any other combination, we get:
$$|\phi(n, t_1) - \phi(n, t_2)| \le n|t_1 - t_2|$$

Now pick any $s \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then:
$$|\phi(n, t_1 -s) - \phi(n, t_2-s)| \le n|(t_1-s) - (t_2-s)| = n |t_1 - t_2|$$

Comment: Thanks for this, but $s$ is not irrelevant, it's the input of the function. The function is defined as $\phi^n_s=(ns)\wedge 1\vee 0$ and then for any $t_1,t_2\geq 0$ we look at $|\phi^n_{t_1-s}-\phi^n_{t_2-s}|$.

Comment: @J.Smith I mean irrelevant for the inequality :) If above answered your question, do not forget to mark it answered.